# Replace VMware with LXD running inside wsl?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, lxd

Is it a good idea to replace VMware with LXD running in wsl (Ubuntu) or will it run way worse than a vm in vmware? I really want solid performance and I’m not sure if wsl can get me that.

Comment: Try both and judge for yourself. Offering any metrics that demonstrate "solid performance" would help.

Comment: VMware and LXD in WSL are different beasts, if you want *Virtual Machines* you should stick to VMware, LXD is not a suitable solution for non-Linux VMs so if you have ANYTHING that needs non-Linux you should use VMware.  Additionally, LXD in WSL doesn't *stay* online or autostart due to how it is initialized in Windows.